# grouping sequence of integers into as equal as possible bins

Tags: python, r, constraints, cluster-analysis

I'm chunking text, trying to create "as equal as possible" length chunks by combining text groups (think sentences with character lengths). I have the sentences is a sequence (I'm working in `r` but could equally work in `pandas` or `python` lists, the data is originally `json`).

So I'm seeking a function that takes an ordered set of numbers and groups them (in sequence) to minimize the number of groups and the divergence of the group size from a goal.

e.g. Take `[460, 100, 200, 200, 20]` and a goal of `500`, then as output produce `{1: [460], 2: [100, 200, 200, 20]}`

So, given a goal of 500, we start with the first item (460), then know not to include the second item (100) in the first group because it is better to be 40 under, than 60 over. So we start a second group that starts with 100, easily adding the next two items (200, 200). The last item would push the second group up to 520, but is added anyway, because it's better to be 20 over than have a short final group (which would be 480 under).

I can't decide if this is interval cutting (`cut_width` from `ggplot2` doesn't work) or a type of constrained agglomerative clustering?

Anyway, I've written a function that kinda works, checking for overage/underage while iterating but I had to special case for the last value. But it actually seems harder than this, because there could be a series of small values at the end that should be added. So maybe it's recursive? Could this be complicated enough to need a linear constraint programming approach? Or am I missing something much easier :)

Anyone know libraries etc that implement something like this?

Comment: how would you group `[460, 100, 200, 200, 20, 200, 30]`?

Comment: `{1: [460], 2:[100, 200, 200], 3: [20, 200, 30] }` which would give group totals of `[460], [500], [250]`, with differences of `40, 0, 250` (or total diff `290`)  Hmmm, or would it be `{1: [460], 2:[100, 200, 200, 20], 3: [200, 30] }` which would give `460, 520, 230` for diffs of `40, 20, 270` (total diff `330`) Nope, that's worse. So optimization means inspecting the distribution of differences, probably prefer to minimize std dev. Time for a  linear solver, I think :)